# Django - Models - overriding delete()

Tags: django, django-models

I just need to send a mail notification whenever a model is deleted. I can achieve this by overriding delete() method. But, the notification mail should specifies the current user who actually deleted this model. Is there any way to get the current user inside delete() method?

Comment: What if a model is deleted from the shell where there is no user?

Comment: @Ignacio Our assumption is that, In a business scenario, admin can only delete this model in admin interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The correct way to hook generically in to events such as deletion is to use signals and NOT to override the delete method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_delete
2. In both cases you cannot get the user, because there may be no user, as when deletion happens from a console, or in some other manner
3. if you need to deal with user-triggered deletes, the solution is to restrict deletion to only occurring in views, and wrapping those views to deal with deletion in whatever way is appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do this in a view, so you've got access to the user. For example:

```
def my_view(request):
    # Send an e-mail containing request.user
    object = Model.objects.get(id=123)
    object.delete()
```